# Invalid <url-pattern> jsp/* in filter mapping in eap 6.4

Tags: jboss

I checked all the other url-pattern related issues but they do not solve my problem. so here it is:

I have a definition as follows in web.xml:

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>ManageFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/jsp/*.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Exception throwed on start. Saying that :

```
 Invalid <url-pattern> /jsp/* in filter mapping
```

I have tried different version as follows :

```
 <url-pattern>jsp/*.do</url-pattern>
```

But it does not work. Same error is being raised.

How can I make it work? Or what is the working version of this url-pattern?

Thank you.

Full exception message :

```
        15:32:52,179 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) JBWEB001097: Error starting context /E_LifePensionWeb: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBWEB000278: Invalid <url-pattern> /jsp/*.do in filter mapping
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.validateFilterMap(StandardContext.java:2030) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addFilterMap(StandardContext.java:1972) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
            at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.processWebMetaData(JBossContextConfig.java:413) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
            at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.applicationWebConfig(JBossContextConfig.java:267) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:369) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:162) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
            at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(JBossContextConfig.java:260) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:115) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3720) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
            at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
            at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
            at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
            at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

Comment: Try using `jsp/*` only

Comment: Let me explain it a bit further to make the big picture clear. 
I have two filters, one is filtering all .do files and the other which I am having problems is handling the .do files only under a subfolder. So, the .do files which must be filtered by managefilter Filter class is staying under JSP subfolder. The issue is I can not give a subfolder and .do prefix et the same time to a url-pattern as it gives me the error Invalid url-pattern. Thanks.

Comment: I solved the issue by giving all the do files a seperate filter-mapping with full names. 
But now the REQUEST object (httpsservletrequest) disappears during forward from action to jsp to filter. I think this has something to do with struts bean settings. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: Can you share the code and elaborate on your problem?

Comment: Hi, I asked a new question for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56835084/forwarded-request-is-not-passed-and-an-empty-one-is-being-processed-jboss-eap-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved by giving all .do paths separately in web.xml

Thanks